# How to add decimals to number?

Tags: php

I need to add decimals to numbers that represent money. I want it to automatically calculate where to add the decimal point, here's an example of what I want, it should explain it better:

Input: $000 Output: $0.00

Input: $151 Output: $1.51

Input: $20300 Output: $203.00

Comment: What is your condition of adding decimal point in your number representing logic. Will it always add decimal point at the before last two digits of your number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your numbers are starting without decimals, you will have to assume that the last two numbers of the string are your interests.

You could create a simple function to convert your numbers under the assumption of the last two characters being the decimal places.

```
$number = 20300;

function convertToDecimal($number) {

    if( $number == 0 ) {
        return number_format($number, 2);
    }

    $beginning = substr($number, 0, -2);
    $end       = substr($number, -2);

    return $beginning . '.' . $end;

}

echo convertToDecimal($number);
```

**Returns:**
`203.00`

Comment: When `$number` = 000. Your answer outputs `.0`.